# NET 5 returns wrong DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek

Tags: c#, .net, calendar

Can somebody tell me how to get the right value from DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek when using NET5?

The culture I'm investigating on is "en-AU".

https://dotnetfiddle.net/v0RAV4 (.NET 4.7.2) vs https://dotnetfiddle.net/FYV8OW (NET 5).

The correct value is Monday. Why does NET5 return Sunday? How can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: Did you report this bug to Microsoft?

Comment: When running this in a NET5 console app on my machine, it works and returns Monday. Might be something about the machine where you are testing? I use Windows and have everything up to date. If there is an issue with your environment, you should report it to MS, including things like what OS you have (linux) as I see some interesting info in [these bug reports](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues?q=label%3Aarea-System.Globalization+firstdayofweek+is%3Aclosed)